# My slayer exciter circuit doesn't work properly

Tags: transistors, batteries, transformer, resonance, tesla-coil

today I tried to make my own Tesla coil circuit according to the schematic below, except that I have changed the number of turns on the secondary and primary so could get a higher output voltage (1 to 500+ turns). That's what I was trying to do. But I have come across a problem. I used Power transistor (BD243C) instead of the 2222A. I wired up my circuit according to the schematic below with red LED, 9V battery but without switch to see if it's at least working.

The circuit doesn't work as expected. My LED didn't light up, transistor is heats up. There are voltage drops in the circuit which I probed but no sign of high voltage output. Can anyone notice something weird and tell me?

[image]

[image]

Thanks to everyone who post a sensible and helpful answer.

Comment: 1. This is not a Tesla coil. 2. You probably need more then 1 turn in your primary for sufficient inductance to resonate at a low enough frequency for the transformer to switch. 3. Changing transistors could affect bias needed and make it not operational at all. 4. Shorten all your leads and heat sink the transistor.

Comment: @MadHatter, thanks for clarification it's not Tesla coil. I have scavenged this transistor I used from the old Tesla coil which had less turns. So I think transistor is good, no?

Comment: Have you tried swapping the leads going to your primary coil in case it's out of phase?

Comment: @MadHatter you mean the right lead should go to the resistors and the left lead to the collector of the transistor according to the picture I have taken?

Comment: Yes. If they are backwards, your feedback from the secondary will be 180* out of phase.

Comment: @MadHatter swapped, doesn't seem to work

Comment: I see a number of issues. One, you will not get enough of a field around a single primary turn to induce much current in the secondary. It will also raise the resonant frequency significantly. Power transistors cannot switch at those speeds. You need to bring that number of turns up. Two, it looks like you have overlapping turns in your secondary (which looks horribly sloppy to me). That will cause issues as well. You should wind a single, smooth layer of wire without overlapping any turns.

Comment: Three, don't change the components and then complain that it's not working. Get yourself a 2222A transistor. Even if you have to salvage one, they are extremely common and easy to find. Or at least learn how transistors work and how to read a datasheet, and select a proper transistor that will work for this exact coil, not some other coil. Four, as MadHatter suggested, shorten the leads. They add inductance and resistance to the circuit, which can cause it to fail.

Comment: Five, your solder joints look very poor (cold joints). You should first learn how to solder correctly, and THEN try resoldering them *properly*. Cold joints often lead to intermittent contact

Comment: Thanks for the tips

Comment: @DerStrom8 what type of wire would you recommend me for this? I used 0,1mm copper wire which is very thin and it's hard to wind it properly with one layer.

Comment: @MerryGR There's another potential issue. 0.1mm wire is much too thin and adds significant resistance to your secondary. I would shoot for between 0.2 and 0.3mm for a coil that size.

Comment: @DerStrom8, thank you for your time. I thought as well that thinner the wire, more the resistance. And one question, does it matter if I use magnetic wire or normal copper wire? :)

Comment: @DerStrom8 also I'd like to understand one thing.. I can't just freely choose how many turns I want to have on the secondary and on the primary (for example 3 to 1,000) and so on.. or can I? Or can I have 1 to 1,000 as well? I think I need to have a proper inductance on the primary.. so 1 turns is total bullshit

Comment: @MerryGR "magnetic" wire is just copper wire which is insulated with a thin layer of varnish and often used in magnetic applications such as motors, transformers, etc. As long as there is an insulating coating on the wire, it will be fine. As for selecting turns ratios, you simply need to take into account the resulting switching frequency due to the inductance and capacitance of the secondary, and make sure your switching circuit can handle it.

Comment: @DerStrom8 so basically I need to find switching speed of my transistor, and according to it, I should find out at which frequency the coil resonates with parasitic capacitor. The frequency I get from the calculation will be the frequency the transistor will switch at?

Comment: @DerStrom8 also, I would need at least 100m of 0.3mm copper wire to make a decent slayer exciter circuit. But they are quite expensive, or not? I've seen one for 9€.

Comment: I found a proper transistor for this switching application TIP35C. It's high power, fast switching NPN transistor. Allowing 25 A of collector current.